# Black line appears when rendering in cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

[image]

When rendering using cycles the hair mesh overlaps with the face mesh and a black line appears.

How do I get rid of the black line?

**Updated:** Wire frame view

[image]

Comment: looks like that is a single hair . Go to particle edit and cut that single hair

Comment: I'd say that character mesh shouldn't consist of several disconnected parts like hairs, ears, head, neck and stuff. It's usually done as one mesh (which is more complex but will let you avoid problems down the road like this in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hair mesh is going inside the face and due to that line is showing while render.

you may edit the hair mesh and pull outside few vertices to remove this line. 
So while you are in edit mode Edges should look like this:

[image]

**Updated:**
Problem area is seems to be here:

[image]

These 2 vertices are going under the face mesh.

I cant reproduce the black line though, but here is how it might be issue and fix

Problem:

[image]

Grab these vertices :
[image]

Move vertices out of the face like this:
[image]

Comment: when apply physics to hair and move slightly. 
sometimes the hair mesh is going insde the face.
How do I make the black line disappear when the meshes intersect?

Comment: Please upload a wire frame view. You may hit Z key to get this view

Comment: wire frame view uploaded.

Comment: Please have a kind look to updated answer

Comment: Welcome, I am glad it worked for you. Thank you very much for accepting answer :)